# Find element byXpath failing when reading from a spreadsheet cell

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I've structured my automated tests in such a way that the Xpath element is stored in a spreadsheet.

I'm using Apache POI to read the cell and I then use the value of the cell in the following line of code (buttonID being the value that gets read from the spreadsheet):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(buttonID));
```

It tells me that it can't find the button, but when I debug it, the value for buttonID is exactly the same as below (which works):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newsletter-sign-up\"]/a"));

debug: buttonID = "//*[@id=\"newsletter-sign-up\"]/a"
```

The code I'm using to retrieve the Xpath value is:

```
String myValue = this.sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).toString();
```

and the value of the cell is:

//*[@id=\"newsletter-sign-up\"]/a

I've tried enclosing it in double quotes in excel, but that also makes no difference. Is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Please share the HTML or URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the xpath and try:

```
//*[@id="newsletter-sign-up"]/a
```

or

```
//*[@id='newsletter-sign-up']/a
```